# Batch file to Auto update date in file name with for-in-do loop

Tags: batch-file, for-in-loop

I have a question about batch files today as I am completely new to them.  I want to create a master batch file to update other batch files with a date in the file name.
For example, File name = test file(20150101).txt.  I want to create a batch file to automatically update the date at the end of the file name, so I dont have to change it each time.  I have tried using

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a IN (test file(20150101)) DO (
SET _Month=%%a
SET _Day=%%b
SET _Year=%%c
)
ECHO Month %_Month%
ECHO Day %_Day%
ECHO Year %_Year%
```

This does not seem to work for what I am trying to do.  Is thier a better way to get it donePlease go easy on me as I am completly new to this

Comment: Hi--just wanting to maybe save you a lot of pain and suffering and time.  Batch language is very difficult to learn and understand when it comes to parsing text, reading, writing and manipulating data, etc.  If you are just getting into scripting, skip learning batch and focus on PowerShell as it is much easier to learn and much more powerful.

Comment: PowerShell is not nearly as portable as batch, nor are the commands as simple to remember. PowerShell is extraordinarily verbose, and looks like it was developed by somebody with a typing fetish. Batch scripts can be run by simply double-clicking them. PowerShell has to be properly configured on the system before a script can be run, which makes deploying scripts to multiple computers excruciating.

Comment: Why parse the file name at all? Why not just generate a timestamp based on the current date and simply rename the file? Or are you planning on having the user input a date and then the batch file searches for other files with that date in the name? I'm unclear about what you're asking.

Comment: Magoo,  It seem to read the file now, but how do I get it to display the file name and updated date once it reads the new date into the variable?

Comment: @magoo.  Please refer to previous post.

Answer (score 0):

Your line :

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a IN (test file(20150101)) DO (
```

will generate a syntax error `) was unexpected at this time` because batch sees the first `)` as closing the first parenthesis (it's actually regarding the second `(` as just another character with no special meaning). Hence batch interprets this as

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a IN (two strings)) DO (
```

and objects to the second `)` where it's expecting `do`.

Next problem is that your filename appears to be `test file(20150101).txt` but you've entered `test file(20150101)`. This may or may not be significant.

The classic cure is to escape the rogue parenthesis with a caret:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a IN (test file(20150101^)) DO (
```

but this won't work because batch will still see two strings, and neither is likely to be a filename.

So the cure for this is

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a IN ("test file(20150101)") DO (
```

Naturally, his isn't the end of the story. Since this is a `"quoted string"` batch will deliver that precise string to `for` for tokenising. Actually, this appears to be precisely what you desire to do, but `for /f` is generally used to read the contents of a file rather than tokenising a text string. To read the contents of a file `test file(20150101)` you'd code `FOR /F "usebackqtokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a IN ("test file(20150101)") DO (` - noting that `test file(20150101)` and `test file(20150101).txt` are two distinct filenames.

So - next step is to fix the problem with

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a IN ("test file(20150101)") DO (
```

This will assign to `%%a`..`%%c` the tokens from the string in quotes, using the specified delimiter(s.) Since there is no `/` in that string, the entire string would be assigned to `%%a`.

You appear to be interested in the `20150101` part, so

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=()" %%a IN ("test file(20150101)") DO (
```

would tokenise `test file(20150101)` to `test file` `20150101` and *nothing*

Actually, you only need the second token, so

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a IN ("test file(20150101)") DO (
```

would assign `20150101` to `%%a` so

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a IN ("test file(20150101)") DO (set var=%%a)
```

would assign that value to `var`.

Next step is to use substringing to apply the values to the variables you want to use.

```
set "_year=%var:~0,4%"
set "_month=%var:~4,2%"
set "_day=%var:~6,2%"
```

should handle that job happily.

What you do with it after that is anyone's guess...

Comment: Magoo, Thanks for your help. It seem to read the file now, but has not updated the date in the file name when I check the actual file?  Basically I will recieve files in the format - examplefile(20150505), but the date will be incorrect.  I need the script to auto update the date in the forementioned format

Comment: You don't say how you want to rename the file or where the filename is coming from. Perhaps they're in variables - you don't reveal that. The command to do a rename is `ren "test file(20150101)" "newname" but without knowing what you want to rename the file to, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Again thanks for your response.  The file does not necessarily have to be renamed.  I just need the date portion in the file name to be updated to the current date every time I run the script on a new file I receive, which will have the incorrect date. The file will be (.sql) files I will be receiving from an external source.  I don't need to change any contents in the file, just the date portion of the file name. If I was to use the command ren "test file(20150101).  how would I replace the date with the current date?   I hope this makes more sense